# How to make images appear after pushing buttons?

Tags: python, image, button, tkinter

I'm trying to make a memory game and I want the images to appear after I press the buttons. As the code is now, the images appears right away. I'm sure there is an easy way to make the images appear as if they are "behind" the buttons when pushed, but since I am a beginner at this I can't get it to work. Is there anyone that could give me some advice?

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

root=Tk()

topFrame=Frame(root)
topFrame.pack()
bottomFrame=Frame(root)
bottomFrame.pack(side=BOTTOM)

def showImage(kitten):
        if kitten == 1:
                load1 = Image.open('Kittens1.GIF')
                render1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage (load1)

                img1 = Label(image=render1)
                img1.image = render1
                img1.pack()

        if kitten == 2:
                load1 = Image.open('Kittens2.GIF')
                render1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage (load1)

                img1 = Label(image=render1)
                img1.image = render1
                img1.pack()        

def kitten(button):
        if button == 1:
                picture = showImage(1)
                return picture

        if button == 2:
                picture = showImage(2)
                return picture

        if button == 3:
                picture = showImage(3)
                return picture
        if button == 4:
                picture = showImage(4)
                return picture

        if button == 5:
                picture = showImage(5)
                return picture       

        if button == 6:
                picture = showImage(6)
                return picture       

number1 = 1
number2 = 2
number3 = 3
number4 = 4
number5 = 5
number6 = 6


button1= Button(topFrame, text="button1", fg="red", command=kitten(number1))
button2= Button(topFrame, text="button2", fg="blue", command=kitten(number2))
button3= Button(topFrame, text="button3", fg="green", command=kitten(number3))
button4= Button(bottomFrame, text="button4", fg="purple", command=kitten(number4))
button5= Button(bottomFrame, text="button5", fg="orange", command=kitten(number5))
button6= Button(bottomFrame, text="button6", fg="yellow", command=kitten(number6))

#packar dem för att visa dem. För att få dem efter varandra på en rad, skriv side=LEFT. annars packas de bara uppe på varandra.
button1.pack(side=LEFT)
button2.pack(side=LEFT)
button3.pack(side=LEFT)
button4.pack(side=LEFT)
button5.pack(side=LEFT)
button6.pack(side=LEFT)


root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

When you create the buttons the callback function will run right away if you call the function, i.e. ends the function name with parentheses: `command=kitten(number1)`. Normally you would just provide the function name without parentheses.

To call a function with arguments from a button you can use `lambda`, see example below:

```
button1= Button(topFrame, text="button1", fg="red", 
                command=lambda: kitten(number1))
```